# How do I check if my domain is grandfathered?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I have thoroughly read through the updated google API Terms and Conditions:

https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/standard-plan-2016-update

Specifically, this excerpt:

*Active domains created before June 22, 2016, continue to be able to access the Google Maps JavaScript API, Static Maps API, and Street View Image API without an API key. They are not affected by keyless access being unavailable for new domains.*

My question is, how do I figure out if my domain is grandfathered and can continue to call the static maps API without the API_KEY parameter?

Comment: Was your domain using static maps prior to June 22, 2016?  Then it is grandfathered.  However, you **should** add a key to any new maps you add to your website (as keys are now required per the TOS), existing requests should keep working (until google changes the TOS to remove the grandfathering).  The general answer to your question, is if your site existed before June 22, 2016 and was using static maps without a key, it is grandfathered for static maps.  (the other test is do static maps work on your domain without a key? if they do, it is grandfathered)

Comment: Well the thing is, I was actually using the static maps API to embed map APIs in email. That's why I am having trouble figuring it out. Technically one a user opens the email, the API call happens through the email client. Having said that, we do offer "hosted" versions of the emails, where a user is able to open the email in a browser, which is through our company domain, so I'm wondering how I figure out if that domain is grandfathered

Comment: If the static maps were being referenced on your domain prior to June 22, 2016, then it should be grandfathered for those accesses.  API calls from the email client are a different thing.  Which are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can test if your domain was whitelisted by trying to load a map without an API key. If you manage to get the static map image it means you were whitelisted.

The whitelist has 25000 queries per day limit which is equivalent to the free quota limit when you are using a key.

To be able to monitor your usage and, if needed, get more quota it would be best for you to start using an API key.  You can then [check quota and monitor your usage in the Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/static_maps_backend/quotas)