# google static maps 403 error

Tags: http-status-code-403, google-maps-static-api

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

In this subdomain-site, the static map will apear without key:
http://ag16.stewede.ch/thom.html

The same html code, but another domain:
http://praxisgemeinschaftamgleis.ch/thom.html

the map is broken and gives back the above mentioned error.
Why is that so?
Thanks, Stefan

PS: The first link works fine without a key. Now I've added one to the second link. But also with a key. It won't work! What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

[You need to use API keys](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html).

In [praxisgemeinschaftamgleis.ch](http://praxisgemeinschaftamgleis.ch/thom.html) the request for the map gets this error response from the API:

```
The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This service requires an API key.
```

This is new, since June 22, 2016.

See also [How do I check if my domain is grandfathered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828155/how-do-i-check-if-my-domain-is-grandfathered)